# JPS-04201: Cannot grant permission(s). Grant already exists for grantee [GranteeEntry]

Tags: java, weblogic, oracle12c, osb, codebase

How to solve the above error thrown during system policy creation in weblogic server using codebase.

Comment: error looks like
 JPS-04201: Cannot grant permission(s). Grant already exists for grantee [GranteeEntry: codeSource=file:${domain.home}/servers/${weblogic.Name}/tmp/_WL_user/oauth2/- principals=[]].

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.